# Coldfusion CGI.HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE seems not to work in IE

Tags: tomcat, caching, coldfusion, railo

To prevent browsers from loading a file every time, I make use of the HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE header. I check if the header is not filled or after the expire date. If that's not true, I return a 304 statuscode:

```
<cfset modSince = "#cgi.HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE#">
<cfif modSince EQ "" || modSince NEQ "" AND ParseDateTime(modSince).after(datum)>
    <cfheader name="Last-Modified" value="#SimpleDateFormat.format(datum)#">
    <cfheader name="Expires" value="#SimpleDateFormat.format(expirevalue)#">
    <cfcontent reset="true" type="#mimetype#" file="#bestand#">
<cfelse>
    <cfheader statuscode="304" statustext="Not Modified" />
</cfif>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox (the file is loaded by cache, as the developer tools states the file returns a 304 status code). IE (8, 9, 10 tested) not so, as that status code is always 200. Do I need some special header, to force IE to send it's if-modified-since header?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to manage this functionality yourself.  Let the browsers do the work they are designed to do.  If you set the `Expires` header to some point of time in the future the browsers should "automatically" do what you are trying to do; use the locally cached version.  Once the `Expires` time has passed the browser should request a fresh copy.

You will also want to set the `Cache-Control` header. This page gives a pretty good description of the process: [Increasing Application Performance with HTTP Cache Headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers). *Note: If both Expires and max-age are set max-age will take precedence.*

Comment: The reason I want to this: The file I recieve from the server can be changed by an user (it's a image), so you can´t just set ´Expires´ to some random date. Therefore I don't want to cache client-side (i.e. the browser always needs to ask the server for a new file). But what can be done to prevent downloading the same file when it is not changed, is check server-side. When the file is not changed, just return a 304 status. And there it goes wrong in IE: the if-modified-since header is empty --> so the file is downloaded again. Btw, I did add cache-control: no-cache, but no difference either.

Comment: Okay, I understand.  This is also described in the article that I [referenced under Conditional requests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#conditional-requests). This should still be controlled by the browser and web server. You should not need to do this in your code. What platform are you using (web server, operating system, Java EE server)?

Comment: I am using tomcat, with Railo (coldfusion). "You should not need to do this in your code" --> in the article you referenced, they also do it in their [code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#implementation). Check the samples for rails and java.

Comment: You set the headers in your code but you should not need to check for and send back the 304 response. That part should be handled for you after setting the headers appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps tomcat works differently than IIS. My statements are referring to IIS and it caches images by default. I can check my log files and see that requests for images, css, js, files are getting 304 responses without me doing anything to make that work. If the file changes then they will get the new file. I am assuming that tomcat should work this way as well.